# how to get search results from google custom search api with strict AND conditions between the keywords

Tags: google-custom-search

I am using google custom search api, to programmatically query with keywords. How can I make sure that the results I get are only those that are based on all the keywords, for example, if I search for "Jack money laundering", I need only those results which have both Jack and money laundering, instead of those results containing either of them?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish what you're talking about is to educate your searchers on how to ensure they only get those results themselves. Otherwise, you'd have to programmatically determine that "Jack" was it's own search term and "money laundering" was a single term. You could wrap each word in quotes but that doesn't solve your problem because you would get results for entries containing "Jack", "money", and "laundering", but not necessarily "money laundering" together as a term.

I would reproduce the tips and instructions here: http://www.google.com/advanced_search for your users. Google's search should be sophisticated enough for most instances but if you really need that ability, your users need to take on some of the responsibility of educating themselves (with your help, of course) to accomplish what you're trying to let them accomplish.